# How to use Auth:user() in middleware properly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to redirect to logout if user has role 'teacher'. I tried to do that with middleware but I dont know what is the problem here. It says

> This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.

, sometimes **Auth:user()** is null for no reason I guess.

Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role == User::ROLE_TEACHER) {
            return redirect()->route('logout');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
       .....
        'noTeacher' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfTeacher::class,

    ];
```

HomeController:

```
$this->middleware('noTeacher', ['only' => 'index']);
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
...
});
```

Comment: Does the `'logout'` route also use the middleware that checks the role? If so then the middleware will just continue to check the role and send to `'logout'` and check again there etc.

Comment: Have you tried `$request->user()->role`?

Comment: Please show your routes file as well

Comment: Okay I'll show you my routes structure

Comment: Are you sure you haven't added the middleware to the web group? Seems like it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. Its MiddleWare

```
class CheckPaAuth {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->role == "Parent") {
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                auth()->logout();
                return redirect("login")->withErrors(['Login failed,please try again!']);
            }
        } 
        return redirect("login")->withErrors(['Please first login.']);
    }
}
```

And Its Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'AuthParent' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPaAuth::class,
];
```

And Its web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['AuthParent'], 'prefix' => 'parent'], function() {
    Route::get('profile', 'UserController@edit');
});
```

Comment: Thats code working in my live project, currently your code goes to multiple redirection ?